# Mod_rewrite rule to redirect from a specific path to another one?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect https://a.domain/foo to https://a.domain/WebFOO. The rule that I've created looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/foo$ WebFOO [R]
</IfModule>
```

However, this approach doesn't work. How should I configure a redirection like this?

Comment: Rule looks okay, I'd imagine something else in the conf is set up incorrectly.What exactly doesn't work, do you get an error or it just doesn't redirect?

Comment: @123 I either get a 404 or the appropriated content of /foo (of course depending on whether I've something in htdocs/foo or not :)). So you can say that the redirection just doesn't take place. It feels like the rule is completely ignored by the server.

Comment: You can turn on logging and check whether it is trying to match. Add these lines  `RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9`.  Although if the server is being used currently, this will fill up really quickly.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^foo$ WebFOO [R]
</IfModule>
```